# Unable to slowdown

Tags: idiom-requests

In Turkish we have this idiomatic usage which literally translated as "unable to slowdown," in the sense that the degree of something is building up. For example:

“Unable to slow himself down, the author's simple criticism turned into outright insult in the following pages.”

Is there an idiom that would replace such usage in English?

Answer (score 1):

**out of control**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/control)  idiom

> 1. Without response to manual direction or input.
> 2. Reckless or wild; in an unruly or unmanageable state or manner.

As in:

> I'm sorry for the way I acted last night. I had too much to drink and
>   got a little out of control.

and

> The real estate market in this city is totally out of control.

**be off the rails** is another good idiom to consider in AmE!